# Brackets виснет

Tags: jvm, adobe-brackets

Старый Brackets (не помню какой версии) предложил залить новую версию, установил. При запуске ПО меню доступно, но не реагирует, даже "О программе" не работает. Снес, переустановил до 1.7- все равно не работает. Решил установить Eclipse (так как там тоже можно делать панели для Фотошоп), инсталляция стала ругаться что не поддерживает Java 1.7, установил 8 Java, перегрузил. Eclipse по-прежнему ругается и не устанавливается, Brackets 1.7 по-прежнему не работает, даже закрывать его приходится через Менеджер задач. При открытом Brackets попробовал удалить, возникло предупреждение что будут закрыты Brackets и Node.js:Server-Side Java Script. Из чего сделал предположение что какие-то проблемы с сервером. Скачал и установил NodeJS, установил Brackets 1.10 - результат один и тот же. Версия Java 8, но отчего Eclipse считает что 7 ? Может тут что-то порыть ?

Comment: Может следовало бы  добавть ещё меток в вопрос, а то не совсем понятно - о чём речь.

Comment: не могу придумать , а сбой, ошибка - не добавить пока не будет большой репутации :(

Comment: Удалось запустить только 1.6 версию.. :-(

Comment: Ну вы бы ещё - "головная боль" предложили! Есть готовая метка [adobe-brackets] например.